# Getting session issue in Service class files in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using symfony2 and in Service container file I have an issue with working with session.

this is my service file:

```
public function FinalPrice()
{
    $session = $this->get('Currency');
    return  $session;
}
```

And I have inculuded Response and Session library in the top of the class which is :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
```

I found it in symfony website which easily working with it without any problem in here

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Which says:

```
public function indexAction($bar)
{
    $session = $this->get('session');
    $session->set('foo', $bar);

    // ...
}
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Doobin\CoreBundle\service\GeneralClass::get() in /var/www/doobin92/src/Doobin/CoreBundle/service/GeneralClass.php line 311
```

I also tried :

```
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
```

But it give this error:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Doobin\CoreBundle\service\GeneralClass::getRequest() in /var/www/doobin92/src/Doobin/CoreBundle/service/GeneralClass.php line 311
```

Thank you in adcance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to inject the service container into your service.

```
services:
    your_service:
        class:     YourClass
        arguments: ["@service_container"]
```

And in your service class:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface  as Container;

YourClass {

    protected $container;

    public function __construct(Container $container) {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
}
```

Then you can use `$this->container->get('session');` inside your service.

Answer (score 2):

The `get()` and the `getRequest()` helpers you're trying to use here are part of the Symfony2 base Controller.

- [Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php)

They should be used only in a Controller context once your controller extends the showed above base controller.

If you take a look at the code, you may notice that both of them use the `container` to get the `request_stack` service for `getRequest()`;

```
$this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
```

And any other service for `get()`,

```
$this->container->get($id);
```

As you're trying to call these two methods within a service. You're **NOT** in a Controller Context and the service class you're adding does not provide such helpers.

**To fix that,**

1. You've to inject the service you wanted to call through the `get()`
   helper directly in your service or,
2. Inject the container by adding,

---

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

public YourServiceClass
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
```

to your Service class,

And,

```
your_service_id:
    class:     YourServiceClass
    arguments: ["@service_container"]
```

to your service definition.